# funcion simple de obtener el valor de un input

Tags: javascript, html

apenas estoy empezando en esto de javascript y estoy tratando de hacer algo muy sencillo, un input y un boton, cuando le doy click al boton, me muestra en la consola un valor.
al introducir un valor en especifico en el input, quiero que al darle click al boton, en la consola se muestre un valor en especifico tambien, y sino, si es cualquier otro valor, que muestre otro, simplificando:
si el valor del input es X, quiero que al darle click al boton se muestre Y.
si el valor del input es C,V,Y, etc, quiero que al darle click al boton se muestre Z. dejo el codigo a continuacion:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button")
button = addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value
    if (input == "x"){
        console.log("y")
    }else {
        console.log("z")
    }
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="number" id="input">
  <input type="button" value="enviar" id="button">
</form>
```

el tema es que cuando doy click en cualquier parte del html o en el input mismo, me devuelve el valor del input, cosa que no quiero, quiero que solo cuando, y solo cuando, le doy click al boton, ahi me ejecute la funcion dicha.
gracias!

Comment: hay un error ahi `button = addEventListener` debería ser `button.addEventListener` . Estás asignando el evento al documento y no al boton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, el único erro de tu código es button = addEventListener
Lo correcto es

```
button.addEventListener("click", function (e) ....
```

También nota que no estas usando un boton tipo submit, entonces el prevent default, está e más.

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo siguiente

> 1. Cuando compares valores, usa el triple signo igual `===` es mas estricto
> 2. No es necesario el `event.preventDefault()` pero si quieres lo puedes dejar
> 3. Opcionalmente usa la sintaxis de `querySelector` para obtener los valores o por `id` o por `class` asi mismo es .addEventListener

Te dejo tu código funcional para que lo pruebes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" placeholder="number" id="input">
  <input type="button" value="enviar" id="button">

<script>
    let botton = document.querySelector("#button")
    
    botton.addEventListener("click", function(){
      let caja = document.querySelector("#input").value
    
    if(caja === 'x'){
      console.log("y")
    }else{
      console.log("z")
    }})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: el problema es que cuando hago click fuera del input, me ejecuta ese condicional, por ejemplo, si en el input no escribi nada y hago click fuera, en la consola muestra z, hago 20 veces click fuera y devuelve 20 veces z, y si en el input pongo x y hago click fuera me devuelve y, y no quiero que suceda eso, quiero que SOLO cuando le doy al boton ejecute esa funcion

Comment: prueba mi código hace lo que pides @LuchoK

Comment: @LuchoK copialo completo y pruebalo lo he testeado antes de responderte

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='direccion_mass' maxlength='45' value="carrera de java"   required='required' autofocus>

    <button type="button" id="acciones" class="btn btn-primary mass"  onclick="myFunction()" data-dismiss="modal">massar
                            </button>
```

la funcion de java seria de la siguiente forma

```
   function myFunction(){
      var datos =$('#direccion_mass').val();
      console.info(datos);
   }
```

```js
function myFunction(){
var datos =$('#direccion_mass').val();

console.info(datos);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='form-control' id='direccion_mass' maxlength='45' value="carrera de java"   required='required' autofocus>

<button type="button" id="acciones" class="btn btn-primary mass"  onclick="myFunction()" data-dismiss="modal">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> massar
      </button>
```

Comment: 2 cosas: la primera el lenguaje es javascript no java y la segunda conviene la aclares que en tu ejemplo estas usando jquery igual y no esta de mas