# donde poner el alert() en javascript en un divisor distinto de cero

Tags: javascript, html

hola estoy haciendo una calculadora en html, tengo dos numeros, un resultado y los botones de las distintas operaciones, lo que quisiera saber es donde debo poner el alert() en javascript cuando en una division el divisor es cero y no me aparezca el resultado de infinito? Muchas gracias.
les dejo una parte del codigo

```
$("#division").click(function(){console.log("dividiendo");
    var n1=$("#num1").val();
    var n2=$("#num2").val();
    var res=parseFloat(n1)/parseFloat(n2);
    $("#res").val(res);
    escero(res);})
```

si va ahi o en otro lugar me gustaria saber. muchas gracias.

Comment: en la línea 34 =P , ya hablando en serio habría que ver algo de código para definir el "dónde" o proponer un "cómo"

Comment: click en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/347776/edit) y pega el código en la pregunta ( seleccionando luego y presionando ctrl+k le da formato )

Comment: en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233503/81450 masomenos a la mitad de la respuesta hay un método de cómo hacer el alert

Comment: no me ayuda en realidad xq es diferente la forma en la que el hace el metodo.

Comment: prueba antes del `var res` un  `if ( 0 == parseFloat(n2) ) { alert("No se puede dividir por cero"); return false; }`

Comment: mil gracias... ahi funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Solamente tienes que retornar el alert antes de que se ejecute la operación, saludos.

```js
$("#division").click(function(){

    var n1=$("#num1").val()
    var n2=$("#num2").val()
    
    if(n1 == 0 | n2 == 0) 
      return alert("Hay algún 0")
    
    var res=parseFloat(n1)/parseFloat(n2)
    $("#res").val(res)
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="num1" type="number"> /
<input id="num2" type="number">
<button id="division">Dividir</button>
<input id="res" type="number">
```